# Unicode character does not appear on iOS

Tags: html, css, mobile, unicode, character

I'm having problems with some Unicode character ()  not showing on iOS.

I have this line of code `<p><a class="title" href="index.html">&#128955; Luiso Vázquez</a></p>` using the HTML entity of the character.

It looks good in desktop, but when it comes to Chrome on my iOS device it appears as an outlined square.

Is there anything I can do to solve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It doesn't show up on macOS either. I guess it's just not a well-supported part of Unicode yet.

Answer (score 3):

iOS's font doesn't cover the character you're trying to use. To fix this, you can either

1. Use a web font
2. Use an image of the character
3. Use a different character